# Async ActionMethod - Is this correct

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Just because something works does not mean it is correct. So I would like some feedback on the following code.

A bit of history; I was trying to send / queue e-mails when a user register on our site and ran in to an issue with the thread being blocked, which makes total sense given the fact that the controller by default and associated action methods are sync not async. In order to work around this issue I threw together the following but am not sure if it is the best way.

```
 [HttpPost, AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterAsync(UserRegisterUserViewModel userRegisterUserViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new UserDto
                {
                    UserName = userRegisterUserViewModel.UserName,
                    Password = userRegisterUserViewModel.Password,
                    AuthType = userRegisterUserViewModel.AuthType,
                    Active = 0
                };
            Guid userId = _userService.AddUser(user);
            if (userId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                // Send Registration E-mail
                await Task.Run(() => _userMailer.RegistrationConfirmation(user).SendAsync(),
                               new CancellationToken(false));
                // Display Confirm View
                return PartialView("_RegistrationConfirmation");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Unable to create account");
        }
        return PartialView("_Registration");
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Asking whether code is "good or not" is vague.

Comment: Is this the proper way of handling the sending of the e-mail. Or will it cause me issues later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of "issue" could be caused by an ASP.NET thread being blocked, but regarding your `async`/`await` code:

- There's no point in `new CancellationToken(false)`, which is the same as `CancellationToken.None`, which is the same as just not supplying the `cancellationToken` parameter.
- There is probably no point to `Task.Run`, which executes `SendAsync` on a thread pool thread. If `SendAsync` is a proper `async` method, then it can just be `await`ed directly.

e.g., that line of code could be replaced by:

```
await _userMailer.RegistrationConfirmation(user).SendAsync();
```

**Edit:**

Since `SendAsync` is on `SmtpClient`, you should [wrap this API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#EAP) (using the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)) into an `await`-friendly API (using the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)):

```
public static Task SendTaskAsync(this SmtpClient client, MailMessage message)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  SendCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
  handler = (s,e) =>
  {
    client.SendCompleted -= handler;
    if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
    else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    else tcs.TrySetResult(null);
  };
  client.SendCompleted += handler;
  client.SendAsync(message, null);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then you can `await` the result of `SmtpClient.SendTaskAsync`.

You don't want to use `Task.Run` because this will cause you to [return early from ASP.NET requests, which is a dangerous practice](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) (as I explain on my blog).

Comment: I get an error saying that the operation can't be performed. The thread is blocked which is the reason.

Comment: In that case the problem is probably in `SendAsync`.

Comment: I will try with the SendAsync from the SmtpClient Directly to verify.

Comment: Similar issue, now I get a mesage stating that An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending. I cant use your line: await _userMailer.RegistrationConfirmation(user).SendAsync(); It is void . cant await on void. Task.Run fixes this however.

Comment: Is client.SendCompleted -= handler; supposed to be initialized somewhere outside. I get an error stating that the local variable "handler" might not be initialized before accessing.

Comment: Ah, yes; forgot that compiler quirk. You can just initialize it to `null` and then set it; see the updated answer.

Comment: Works great, I added a another SendAsync method to the Interface and base classes for MVC Mailer, works great so far. The author of MVC Mailer should include support for this. Thanks you are great.

Comment: Glad I could help! `async` support is still relatively new (less than 5 months since RTW), and it'll take some time to work its way through various libraries (it's easiest to support `async` if all the libraries you depend on already support `async`).